Automatically italicize a letter only in math mode
I would like to automatically italicize the letter P (in capitalized form) but only during math mode.
I am aware I could do it but with a new command such as :
\renewcommand{\P}{\mathit{P}}
Perhaps it is easier and simpler to manually write \P each time?
I am using Quarto but this should be the same. Here is my MRE:
---
title: "Italic P"
format: pdf
pdf-engine: lualatex
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{amsmath}
  - \usepackage{unicode-math}
  - \unimathsetup{math-style=french}
  - \usepackage{libertine}
  - \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math} 
  - \renewcommand{\P}{\mathit{P}}
keep_tex: true
---

Italic P in markdown: *P*.

In a display equation: $P$ this should be italic

Command $\P$ is italic but default $P$ is not. 


If you want uppercase Latin letters to be set in slanted/italic math mode rather than in upright math mode mode, you shouldn't set \unimathsetup{math-style=french}. Or is it just the letter P that should be rendered in math-italic mode, whereas all other Latin uppercase letters should be rendered in math-upright mode? Please advise.

@Mico It is indeed just the letter P that I would like to automatically italicize in all my document, but only in math mode.

do you really want \mathit{P} which is text italic in math mode, or the default math italic? and why just P??????

Translating into LaTeX, you have
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\unimathsetup{math-style=french}
\usepackage{libertine}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\renewcommand{\P}{\mathit{P}}

\begin{document}

Italic P in markdown: \textit{P}.

In a display equation: $P$ this should be italic

Command $\P$ is italic but default $P$ is not.

\end{document}

The math-style=french makes uppercase letters in math upright. All of them, because this is the French style.
If you want uppercase letters in math to be in italics, just remove that option. If you want just the “P” (but I'd not know why), change its mathcode.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\unimathsetup{math-style=french}
\usepackage{libertine}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[Scale=MatchUppercase]

\Umathcodenum`P=14799939

\begin{document}

Italic P in markdown: \textit{P}.

In a display equation: $P$ this should be italic

\end{document}



Thank you. Both solutions from yours or @DavidCarlisle work, though I'm currently not looking for lower case italic math characters (I put math-style french in order to have those upright).
I guess the \P solution is also elegant while not intrusive, however the idea is that I want to automate this for the moment.
The reason I wanted to capitalize P is because sometimes the journal want the P value to be capitalized and italicized and sometimes not.

This seems a very strange request but to get just capital P and lowercase letters in math italic

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\unimathsetup{math-style=french}
\AtBeginDocument{\Umathcode`P "0 "3 "1D443}

\begin{document}

ABCPQRxyz ---  $ABCPQRxyz$

\end{document}



It is indeed just the letter P that I would like to automatically italicize in all my document, but only in math mode.

I suggest you define \P as follows:
\renewcommand{\P}{\ifmmode\symit{P}\else\textup{P}\fi}

Note that \P can be used in both math and text mode. The macro \symit is provided by the unicode-math package. Unlike \mathit, \symit is guaranteed to take its argument from the math font rather than from the text font. The use of \textup assures that P will be typeset in upright mode even if the surrouding text is in italics. \P may be used in both text and math mode.

% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{libertine}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}[math-style=french]
\renewcommand{\P}{\ifmmode\symit{P}\else\textup{P}\fi}

\begin{document}
Math-mode $\P$ is italic but text-mode \P{} is not. 
\end{document}

